# Launch concurrent one-off Heroku dynos from PHP

Tags: php, heroku

I am running a (detached) PHP script from the command line, which itself uses `shell_exec()` to launch other PHP scripts. I had expected that each of these scripts would be launched almost immediately, but instead it appears to be waiting for one to complete before the code continues to the next one.

This is essentially what I'm running. How can I allow my script to continue through the foreach loop without waiting for each `shell_exec()` to terminate?

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $output = shell_exec("php path/to/file.php $estab_code") ;
}
```

Really, my expected outcome here is that each `shell_exec()` should trigger a new one-off Heroku dyno to be launched, with all of them running concurrently. However, that doesn't appear to be happening: the executed script seems to be running from the original dyno.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

shell_exec waits for the command to return something.  In order to make that something happen immediately and be empty, you could tack the following onto each command:

```
> /dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

Something like this:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $output = shell_exec("php path/to/file.php $estab_code > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful, I'll give it a try. Do you happen to know how I can use shell_exec to start a new one-off Heroku dyno? It seems the default behaviour is that it runs the process on the running dyno, which defeats the object of me doing this (that is, to run each script concurrently on multiple dynos)

Comment: I've figured out how to do what I want to do using Heroku's API.